# Charges despite free tier for account with credit card

Tags: ibm-cloud

I was testing IBM Bluemix with an assigned credit card.
However after 10 days it shows me, that I will be charged for
10$. I was only creating one 512mb container at the time with one IP
and my volume was always 20GB big. The fees are only showing up in
the summary. If I show charges for my account (joerg.bluemix@higgsboson.tk)
the site just crashes. Is this an accounting bug?

(I already opened some tickets however I got no response for any of them, ...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is looking for help with a billing problem in product the OP is using.

Comment: Please wait some hours until at least some IBM guy, saw this problem. I have no other ways to contact this company, and I know they will see this here. I am sorry they abusing stackoverflow as their extended bug tracker. I have removed all other tags, except bluemix so nobody will see this.

Comment: Mic92, I'm sorry somebody gave you the idea that IBM uses Stack Overflow as their extended bug tracker. We encourage people to open support tickets for billing questions and ask non-technical questions at IBM developerWorks Answers (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html). This is all described in the Bluemix help documentation - https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/support/index.html#getting-customer-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The account balance shows how much the service usage would be billed, not considering the free tier. Anyway the final and aggregated balance shows what you should finally pay, and if the usage is under the free tier of each service the balance will be 0.
Anyway you can contact the IBM Bluemix support through the support widget on your Bluemix dashboard, nor through the support page at

http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport